# How can I do square where I can put text?

Tags: tables, formatting

I want to do something like this in LaTex

[image]

Can anyone help me please?

What I need is something that I can create a square where I can put text, and inside such square to create another square. The first square must always have its sides with the margins I have as its limits.

It also must ocurr that if I begin a square in some page and this follows until more pages, then the following pages must have also the margins.

Indeed, I am searching a LaTex version of what word call "insert square text"

[image]

[image]

[image]

I need that the following blue lines appear and that the yellow place is not empty

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: are there no gaps in your text

Comment: will this be split across pages

Comment: I have added additional details, I hope they can help, If they are not enough please tell me

Comment: Word is an editor.  LaTeX is a programming language for typesetting.  There are many ways to create frames (such as \fbox).  However, frames that break across pages are harder.  Mdframed and tcolorbox are the only ones I know of.

Comment: John Kormylo, I have tried with Mdframed and it works, but there is one problem, the sides of the frame are opaque, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The main two packages to draw all sorts of frames in LaTeX are [`mdframed`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) and [`tcolorbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox). Here's an example using `tcolorbox`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\newtcolorbox{textbox}{
    sharp corners,
    colback=white,
    colframe=black,
    boxrule=.5pt,
    breakable,
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-5]
\begin{textbox}
    \lipsum[2][1-5]
    \begin{textbox}
        \lipsum[3][1-5]
    \end{textbox}
    \lipsum[4][1-5]
    \begin{textbox}
        \lipsum[5][1-5]
    \end{textbox}
\end{textbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks nice Vincent,  it is what I am searching for, but why I don't get the same results when I use the code, why?, I copied the code

Comment: @Ratamágica well it's hard to answer this question without any code... Did you load the package `tcolorbox`? When you copied the code, did you copy the definition of the `textbox` environment from my example?

Comment: Vince, Yes I did everything. I copy all the code you shared

Comment: @Ratamágica when you try to compile my code, do you have any errors? What happens? I won't be able to help you if you can't be more specific.

Comment: @Vincent, probably you have outdated LaTeX installation. Try to upgrade it. Given example works fine with recent version of MIKTeX.

Comment: @Vince, I have solved the problem, I just deleted "sharp corners," of the code. But I have found other problem. This is that when I write inside textbox enviroment and what I have written has and extesion bigger than a page, the frame doesn't appear complete. How can I solve this?

Comment: @Ratamágica as @Zarko said, maybe your LaTeX installation is not up to date and it is the reason the option `sharp corners` does not work. In that case, you should update it. As for the page breaks, I updated my example to add the key `breakable` to the `textbox` environment, which will allow page breaks.

Comment: @Vince, breakable doesn't work.  I added it, but the same problem occurs. I will be more specific. I begin textbox in a certain page where in the pdf is the left, I write what I need inside the enviroment textbox, but when I compile occurs that all the table is printed in another page.

Comment: @Vincent, see the picture I have loaded to my description of the problem please, here the problem is clear

Comment: @Ratamágica inner boxes are always unbreakable, I suspect this is what causes the issue. You could replace the key `breakable` with `enforce breakable`, but the `tcolorbox` manual does not recommend to do this. See section 19 in the manual for more details.